# Gmail API: forcing the authorization to reprompt the user

Tags: c#, gmail-api

The credentials authorizing access to gmailAPI seem to be cached somehow.  When I change the client ID and secret, and email address, nothing changes.  Also, when I change the scope, nothing changes.  I am trying to force the credentials to refresh. Is there a way to force the credentials to reprompt the user?

Is there a file I can find and delete?

I am using c# and the gmail api package from nuget. The code for credentialing is:

```
 _emailAddress = Settings.EmailAddress;
string clientSecret = Settings.ClientSecret;
string clientId = Settings.ClientId;
ClientSecrets clientSecrets = new ClientSecrets {ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret};
UserCredential credential;
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    clientSecrets,
    Scopes,
    "user",
    CancellationToken.None).Result;

_service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
   HttpClientInitializer = credential,
   ApplicationName = "Draft Sender", //applicationName,
});
```

Also, once I credential, my scope is set: cannot change scope until I delete and renew the secret and clientID.  Also, it takes two run-throughs in order to generate the credentials, the first resulting in an error, but the second resulting in a prompt to authorize.

I'm pretty sure that this is happening because the credentials are cached somewhere, somehow, even though I haven't specified any storage...but I don't know for sure.  Either way, the issue seems to depend on code inside the gmail api package, but I am having trouble finding a solution for what I am dealing with.

Ultimately, I need to deploy a functionality to an ASP website that will access the gmail account as a repository for emails, so I need to have this authorization thing figured out so that the server will have access to the email account upon deployment (or easily after).  It is not really necessary (but desired) that it happen without the intermediate error.

Is there a solution (easy or hard) to control this caching process and handle the permissions?

Comment: Could you elaborate? What library and langauge are you using? I would assume your library still think the token you have is valid, so it doesn't bother with re-authenticating.

Comment: I think that is exactly what is happening.  I went ahead and deleted my secret and clientID and created a new one.  That forced the system to re-authenticate.  But there must be a cleaner way to do it??

I am using C# and the nuget gmail api package.

Comment: I think you should only authenticate once, and use the other neat functions in the library to just refresh the access token when it runs out (usually after an hour) :)

Comment: oh, i knew it would be that easy :)  I will try and see if that works--but I can't be constantly authorizing the email...it should just be authorized once...  And there is the problem with getting it to run on the server: is it possible to deploy with the credentials intact? Otherwise, I have a feeling I'll need to take control of the token somehow..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify where you are storing the response token, it's stored on:

C:\Users\'Your user'\AppData\Roaming\Google.Apis.Auth

If you want to specify the directory look at this: 
(note: you just need to create the directory `App_Data` in your project)

```
string path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data");    
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                         new ClientSecrets
                         {
                             ClientId = "Client_ID",
                             ClientSecret = "Secret_Client"
                         },
                         Scopes,
                         "me",
                         CancellationToken.None,
                         new FileDataStore(path)

                         ).Result;
```